# setImage: does not cause image to change

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, compiler-warnings

I have created two `UIImageView`s in my code:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 60, 180, 180)];
UIImageView *result = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 60, 180, 180)];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view addSubview:result];
[self.view insertSubview:result aboveSubview:background];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]]];
```

When you press a button, this code is executed:

```
- (IBAction)oneToSix {
    int rNumber = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    [result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber, @".png"]]];
}
```

but the image doesn't change.

Also, I am getting these errors:

[image: errors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redeclaring variables in the method scope that were already defined at the class scope. Remove the `UIImageView *` part from your initialization.

Note: it's doing nothing when you change image, because in ObjectiveC, a method call to nil (uninitialized instance member) is valid, and produces no visible result.

Answer (score 1):

```
[result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber, @".png"]]];
```

Note you are only putting the number into that string.  You'll want `%d%@` as the format.

Those aren't errors, they are warnings.  You have an instance variable in your class called `background`.  You also declare a local variable called `background` in your method.  The warning is to let you know that there's a conflict and that it's choosing the local variable over the instance variable.

Comment: How do I get rid of the warning though?

Comment: It's warning you that you're calling two different things by the same name.  To fix this, don't call two different things by the same name.  Pick a different name for one of them.

Comment: In `result`'s case, it appears the problem is that you are using a local variable when you want to access the instance variable.  Remove `UIImageView *` from the line declaring `result` inside your method.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image named `Red` or `Red.png`? Because if it is the latter, you should append the file extension in the `setImage` method with something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [defaults objectForKey:"colour"]]`

Also, you are inserting the `result` imageView twice. Remove the first one.

Comment: `.png` is not necessary. xCode will try to find image by name.